# Get Rendered Layer Onclick React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, render

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    onClickButton : function(){
        //i want layer in this function
    },
    render: function () {
         return (
            <div className="Component">
                  <button onClick={this.onClickButton}>Click Me</button>
            </div>
         ); 
    }
});

function renderNow(data,layer){
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Component data={data} />,
        layer
        );
}
```

called using `renderNow({name: 'John' },someLayer);`

I want `layer` inside the `onClickButton` function which was passed through `renderNow` function.

I tried passing layer to `render` function and `setState` the `layer` but it gave me `StackOverflow` Error

Comment: Please provide the full error.

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer its solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly the layer is and what you would like to achieve, but I suppose you should be able to pass layer as a props to your Component.

```
function renderNow(data,layer){
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Component data={data} layer={layer} />,
        layer
    );
}
```

and then

```
...
onClickButton : function(){
    this.props.layer //i want layer in this function
},
...
```

Comment: Layer is likely a DOM Element, but your answer still holds well.

Comment: i used @technophobia answer tho

Answer (score 0):

Marek's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42317486/984275) is the way I would do it...but there's another way using [`ReactDOM.findDOMNode()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode)

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    onClickButton : function() {
        //i want layer in this function
        const layer = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this); // <-- Here you go
    },
    render: function () {
         return (
            <div className="Component">
                  <button onClick={this.onClickButton}>Click Me</button>
            </div>
         ); 
    }
});
```

**Ref:** https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html

---

### Notice:

The docs generally recommend against breaking through the Component abstraction:

> **Note:**
>
> `findDOMNode` is an escape hatch used to access the underlying DOM node. In most cases, use of this escape hatch is discouraged because it pierces the component abstraction.

Comment: @IMOBAMA I added a notice that I believe you should pay attention to - whatever you're doing can probably be done using the component.  Food for thought.